# array indexing in for each loop C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

what will be the For each loop Code for the below for loop in C# ? stuck on displaying the index positions. thanks your help will be appreciated.

```
 int[] n=new int[5];
        n[0] = 12;
        n[1] = 24;
        n[2] = 36;
        n[3] = 48;
        n[4] = 60;

         //n[5]=2; // will display out of bounds error
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Aray position "+ i.ToString() + " & the value is " + n[i].ToString());
        }
```

I tried this . is there something better ? instead of a guessing the index I wanted to see the index directly.

```
             int a = 0;
        foreach (int i in n)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Aray position " + a + " & the value is " + i);
            a++;

        }
```

Comment: Foreach does not have an index, you can make your own `i` and increment it

Comment: If you _need_ the index then `for` is already the way to go - nothing to gain from `foreach` here

Comment: int a = 0;
            foreach (int i in n)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Aray position " + a + " & the value is " + i);
                a++;
            }

I did the above code .but wanted some way to keep the "a" inside . So that the scope of "a" would get less. thanks anyways

Comment: I found 
Array.IndexOf(n,i)  method . it works inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an override of the `Select`-linq-method to get the `item` and the `index`.

```
var list = n.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Aray position " + item.index + " & the value is " + item.value);
}
```

But as you see, this method is not shorter.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` loop depends on *content*, and in your case, if you need the current index, the best choice is using `for` loop.

explansion: `foreach` loop used `Enumerable` and it's `Enumerator`. in the `Enumerator` there are `Current` property and `MoveNext()` method. So, the `index` is not belong that...

Answer (score 0):

```
     foreach (int i in n)
        {Console.WriteLine("Aray position " + Array.IndexOf(n,i) + " & the value is " + i);
        }
```

Thanks this worked .

Comment: This will only work if `n` contains distinct values only

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short version

```
int[] n = { 12, 24, 36, 48, 60 };

foreach (var item in n.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Aray position {0} & the value is {1}" , item.i, item.x);
}
```